# How to create projection matrix from forward/left/up vectors in webgl

Tags: javascript, 3d, opengl-es, webgl

I have webgl code that uses 3 rotation angles to rotate camera and then it returns forward, left and up vectors. It works fine:

```
function matrixFromPositionAndRotation(aPosition, aRotX, aRotY, aRotZ) {
    var matrix = mat4.create();
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 2000.0, matrix);

    mat4.rotateX(matrix, aRotX);
    mat4.rotateY(matrix, aRotY);
    mat4.rotateZ(matrix, aRotZ);

    mat4.translate(matrix, aPosition);

    return {
        matrix: matrix,
        forward: vec3.create([matrix[2], matrix[6], matrix[10]]),
        left: vec3.create([matrix[0], matrix[4], matrix[8]]),
        up: vec3.create([matrix[1], matrix[5], matrix[9]])
    };
}
```

However I want to do the opposite. I know position, forward, left and up vectors, and I want to calculate projection matrix. I tried the opposite, but it doesn't work:

```
function matrixFromPositionAndVectors(aPosition, aForward, aLeft, aUp) {
    var matrix = mat4.create();
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 2000.0, matrix);

    mat4.translate(matrix, aPosition);

    matrix[0] = aLeft[0];
    matrix[4] = aLeft[1];
    matrix[8] = aLeft[2];

    matrix[2] = aForward[0];
    matrix[6] = aForward[1];
    matrix[10] = aForward[2];

    matrix[1] = aUp[0];
    matrix[5] = aUp[1];
    matrix[9] = aUp[2];

    return {
        matrix: matrix
    };
}
```

Comment: FYI, I think most people call the matrix that `mat4.perspective` makes a  *projection matrix*. The other matrices are have other names depending on how they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to multiply the matrix you have by the one you're creating

```
    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 2000.0, matrix);

    mat4.translate(matrix, aPosition);

    const m = [
      ...aLeft, 0,
      ...aUp, 0,
      ...aForward, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1,
    ];
    mat4.multiply(matrix, matrix, m);
```

Note though that I'd expect `aLeft` to actually be `aRight`. In other words consider the identiy

```
[
  1, 0, 0, 0,    // points right (x = 1)
  0, 1, 0, 0,    // points up    (y = 1)
  0, 0, 1, 0,    // points ??    (z = 1) If you define +Z as forward.
  0, 0, 0, 1,
]
```

For camera matrices -Z is usually forward.

I'm also guessing you're unfamiliar with WebGL (OpenGL) matrices. They call rows "columns"

```
[
  1, 0, 0, 0,    // column 0
  0, 1, 0, 0,    // column 1
  0, 0, 1, 0,    // column 2
  0, 0, 0, 1,    // column 3
]
```

And so the xAxis goes here

```
[
  Xx, Xy, Xz,  0,    // column 0 (xAxis)
   0,  1,  0,  0,    // column 1
   0,  0,  1,  0,    // column 2
   0,  0,  0,  1,    // column 3
]
```

Though of course you didn't post your math library. `mat4` is not part of anything standard so without seeing it we can't know what it's doing, only guess.

you can test though. Do this

```
console.log(mat4.translate(mat4.create(), [11, 22, 33]));
```

You'll likely get

```
[
   1, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0,
  11,22,33, 1,
]
```